# Grouping events by year and by month

Tags: python, django

In my Website I have a timeline view where the user can see all the organized events (upcoming and past), for this I created an Event Model that has a DateTimeField and now I'm trying to group the results to render them in the template. The desired output is:

```
- 2014
-- January
---- event1
---- event2
-- February
---- event1
---- event2
....
- 2015
-- January
....
```

My attempt at grouping by year:

```
        events = {}

        last_year = None
        current_year_events = []

        for event in ProofEvent.objects.all().order_by("date"):
            year = event.date.year

            if year != last_year:
                current_year_events.append(event)
                events[year] = current_year_events
                last_year = year
                current_year_events = []
                print event.title
            else:
                current_year_events.append(event)
                print event.title

        print events
```

Comment: Have a look at `itertools.groupby`

Comment: Do you want to group by month?

Comment: This can also be done in the template fairly easy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup
In your case, `{% regroup events by date.year as years %}`

Comment: Yes, by year first and then by month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trying to group events only for template rendering then it is unnecessary.  You can pass a flat list of events and use [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for event in events %}

    {% ifchanged %}<h2>{{ event.date|date:"Y" }}</h2>{% endifchanged %}

    {% ifchanged %}<h3>{{ event.date|date:"F" }}</h3>{% endifchanged %}

    <div>{{ event.title }}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The output is exactly what I needed. Except that it's event.date|date. I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me